# how to have a double while loop in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, loops, while-loop

I'm developing an appointment calendar application. Still newbie here.

I need help in this area.

I need to have a double looping in columns (`calendarID, Slot, AppointmentDate').

The 'slot' column will have a value of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 upto 28 repeatedly while the calendarID will continuously loop to 868 value. 
The Appointment date will have the value from 1 Aug2013 to 31 Aug 2013 (actually I'm planning to do this for 1 whole year)

expected result

```
calendarID | Slot       |  AppointmentDate      
----------------------------------------------  
    1          | 1         | 1 Aug 2013  
    2          | 2         | 1 Aug 2013    
    3          | 3         | 1 Aug 2013   
    4          | 4         | 1 Aug 2013   
    5          | 5         | 1 Aug 2013   
    6          | 6         | 1 Aug 2013    
    7          | 7         | 1 Aug 2013   
    8          |..until 28 | 1 Aug 2013 
    9          | 1         | 2 Aug 2013    
    10         | 2         | 2 Aug 2013
    11         | 3         | 2 Aug 2013  
    ...until   
    868        | n         | n Month 2013
```

Here is my code that I try seems I'm very far from my desired output.
I edited the code provided by Astrand

```
DECLARE @tblCalendar TABLE(CalendarEntryID INT,
    Slot INT,  ADate Varchar(50))

DECLARE @x int, @y int , @d INT

SET @X = 1 SET @y = 1 SET @d = 1

WHILE @X <= 868
BEGIN 

    WHILE  @Y <=28 AND @d <=31 AND @X <= 868 --LOOP FOR SLOT COLUMN
        BEGIN

        INSERT INTO @tblCalendar (CalendarEntryID,Slot, ADate)
        Values (@x, @y,@d +'/Aug/2013')
                SET @y = @y + 1
                SET @x = @x + 1
        SET @d = @d + 1 
           END
    SET @y = 1  
END

SELECT  *
FROM    @tblCalendar
```

sorry for the trouble of asking and editing my original post.

Comment: Two questions:  Why is @x capped at 80 and @y capped at 16, when your question says 100 and 8?  Also, why is this tagged as VB.NET?

Comment: i just noticed that i wrongly keyin 16 instead of 8, i edited already.
actually the application front end is vb.net

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with your front end - it's all about SQL, so the VB.NET and Calendar tags are not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer to my post, just in case in the future someone like me will have the same question.

```
DECLARE
@x int, @y int, @d date, @i date, @status Nvarchar(50)
SET @X = 1 
SET @y = 1
SET @d = DATEADD (dd, 1 , '31/Jul/2013') -- '2013/07/01' --default date to August
SET @status = 'Available'

WHILE @X <= 868

BEGIN 

WHILE @Y <=28 AND @X <= 868--LOOP FOR SLOT COLUMN
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO  tblCalendar (CalendarEntryID,Slot,Date,Status)
            Values (@x, @y,@d,@status)
            SET @x = @x + 1
            SET @y = @y + 1
            SET @i = @d
        END
SET @d = DATEADD (dd, 1 , @i) -- THIS WILL INCREMENT THE DATE ACCORDING TO SLOT
SET @y = 1  
END
SELECT  *
FROM    tblCalendar
```

Answer (score 3):

OK, this will get you the desired result, but it is questionable. I will try and improve it a bit after that.

```
DECLARE @tblCalendar TABLE(
        CalendarEntryID INT,
        Slot INT
)

DECLARE
@x int, @y int

SET @X = 1 SET @y = 1

WHILE @X <= 100
BEGIN 

    WHILE @Y <=8 AND @X <= 100--LOOP FOR SLOT COLUMN
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @tblCalendar (CalendarEntryID,Slot)
            Values (@x, @y)

                SET @y = @y + 1
                SET @x = @x + 1
            end

    SET @y = 1
END


SELECT  *
FROM    @tblCalendar
```

Another approach would be to make use of an [IDENTITY COLUMN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx)

Something like

```
DECLARE @tblCalendar TABLE(
        CalendarEntryID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
        Slot INT
)

DECLARE
@x int, @y int

SET @X = 1 SET @y = 1

WHILE @X <= 100
BEGIN 

    WHILE @Y <=8 AND @X <= 100--LOOP FOR SLOT COLUMN
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @tblCalendar (Slot)
            Values (@y)

                SET @y = @y + 1
                SET @x = @x + 1
            end

    SET @y = 1
END


SELECT  *
FROM    @tblCalendar
```

But personally I would have gone for

```
DECLARE @Max INT = 100,
        @MaxGroup INT = 8

    ;WITH Val AS (
            SELECT  1 CalendarEntryID
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  CalendarEntryID + 1
            FROM    Val
            WHERE   CalendarEntryID + 1 <= @Max
    )
    SELECT  CalendarEntryID,
            ((CalendarEntryID - 1) % @MaxGroup) + 1 Slot
    FROM    Val
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: wow you are so good!
two thumbs up for this forum.  I did not expect a super fast reply with accuracy. your suggestion code really works, Thanks alot! astander, now how to mark your answer as answer. to put a check mark.

Comment: i have another question i think my mistake that i should put it together with my above post, Id like to also to put some value on the date column  
as stated above i have another column date.
the Slot value (1-8) should loop to the date of a month(1-31.
I edit the above post, in the lower area to know what i mean.
thanks for the big help

Comment: I manage to come up with my own solutions though its something like manual thing.
I just use the update command to put the desired dates base on the slot value which is 1-28.
Thanks a lot people for your precious time ^^,
happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

well since it's SQL I don't think you have to do loop. You can generate this data with recursive CTE easily:

```
with cte as (
    select 1 as calendarID
    union all
    select calendarID + 1
    from cte1
    where calendarID < 100
)
select
    CalendarID, (CalendarID - 1) % 8 + 1
from cte
order by CalendarID
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/18877)