# Developing SCV using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops

I am trying to identify all related records using IDs from two different systems.

I have seen solutions that matches SourceA to SourceB and back to SourceA but obviously this will not pick up everything.

The below table shows that 1-A is seemingly unrelated to 4-C, however when we pair them up we can see that all of the below records are related and the latest ID combination is 4-C.

```
| SystemA_ID | SystemB_ID | Date     | PrimaryA | PrimaryB |  
| 1          | A          | 1/1/2016 | 4 | C |  
| 2          | A          | 2/1/2016 | 4 | C |  
| 2          | B          | 3/1/2016 | 4 | C |  
| 3          | B          | 4/1/2016 | 4 | C |  
| 3          | C          | 5/1/2016 | 4 | C |  
| 4          | C          | 6/1/2016 | 4 | C |
```

What I need is to populate the `PrimaryA` and `PrimaryB` columns with `4` and '`C`' respectively.

I was thinking of doing a double loop similar to the [solution described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18266336/how-to-have-a-double-while-loop-in-sql-server-2008)

However, I could not get it working and also there might be a better solution.

[image]

Comment: A recursive CTE would be helpful here. Using that you would be recursively looking for relations. At the end you can fish out the largest one and store the it back in the original table.

Comment: I might be missing something that has been omitted from the data examples, but this looks like it doesn't need more than some group by / date joining?